Нет питания на USB Raspberry Pi 3b+
После установки Parrot OS Raspberry Pi 3B+ начала сильно греться, в конце зависла, при попытке перезагрузить выдала kernel panic, переустановил на Rpi OS, на портах USB пропало питание, замерял тестером - 0В, сопротивление вроде нормальное, на GPiO все стабильно, ethernet тоже работает. Блок питания 5 вольт/3 ампера, на USB кроме wifi свистка и мыши с клавой ничего не цеплял
